# How to pass props to dynamic route?

Tags: reactjs

I create a list of dynamic routes (Posts) and a component of a single route (Post), but cannot figure out, hou to pass props to each route. I simplified the code, leaving only what concerns the routing.

Here is the Posts component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Post from './Post';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const shutruk = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Shutruk-Nahhunte",
    "info": "Was king of Elam from about 1184 to 1155 BC"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Shilkhak-Inshushinak",
    "info": "Was king of Elam from about 1150 to 1120 BC"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Untash-Napirisha",
    "info": "He was the son of the previous Elamite king"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Kutik-Inshushinak",
    "info": "His father was Shinpi-khish-khuk, the crown prince"
  }
];

class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/posts"><h2 className="center" >Posts</h2></Link><br/>
        <div className="center"><img src={require('../img/orn.png')} alt="" className="orn" /></div>     
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/posts" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/posts/:id" component={Post} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    {
      shutruk.map(shutruk => (
        <h3><Link to={'posts/' + shutruk.id}>{shutruk.title}</Link></h3>
      ))
    }
  </div>
);

export default Posts;
```

The Post component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3></h3> //Here should be each value from "title"
        <h5></h5> //Each "info" value   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

How to do it in the right way?
Many thanks in advance!))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use the render prop pattern and render the Post route with the relevant data

```
<Route path="/posts/:id" render={(props) => {
   const id = props.match.params.id;
   const data = shutruk.find(item => item.id === id);
   if(data) {
       return <Post {...props} {...data} />
   }
   return <Redirect to="/not-found" />
}}  />
```

Comment: Thanks! But what should be in a component? {this.props.info} does'nt work

Comment: this.props.info should work in the Post component if you write your code like above

Comment: Sorry for too much questions, but can U display the whole code of components?)

Comment: @kiten just change the path slightly you can see then: https://codesandbox.io/s/frzvy

Answer (score 2):

[Edited]

Note : Pass the data through Link will work fine when user Click on it. But it will cause a problem, when the user come to the page using url, or just refresh the page, then there is no data. Then you have to check and maybe fetch it when there is no data.

So I think it's better to do this like [@Shubham Khatri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069740/5412278)

---

Please check the React Router doc: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

The `<Link>` accept object value to `to` property,
so you are able to pass the data like this:

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: 'posts/' + shutruk.id,
    state: { shutruk: shutruk }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what should be in a component? {this.props.info} does'nt work

Comment: It will be store in `location`, try`{ this.props.location.state.shutruk.info }`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri oh, I see the problem, thanks! I will edit my answer