# How to pass props to child component based on dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make an ecommerce website with react and react-router-dom. I have different components: `ProductsList`, `Product`, `Details` (about single product).

I am using Context API in a separate file. My `App.js` file looks like this:

```
...imports
const products = useContext(ProductContext)

const App = () => {
   ...
   <Route path="/products/:id">
     <Details products={products} />
   </Route>
}
```

But I want to send details only about the product whose `id` matches the dynamic route id, not the whole array of products. But how do I extract that id? I know I can do it inside the `Details.jsx` file by using `useParams()`. But how do I do that from inside `App.js`?

I just noticed there's a similar [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069587/how-to-pass-props-to-dynamic-route). But I want my `Details` component in its own file and not inside `App`.

Comment: `But I want my Details component in its own file and not inside App` - from where do you planning to render details component?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela from the `App` component which is borrowing `products` from `ProductContext` and passing it to `Details` component when this `products/:id` dynamic route is triggered

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:-

```
...imports
const products = useContext(ProductContext)

const App = () => {
   ...
   <Route path="/products/:id" render={(props) => {
   const id = props.match.params.id;
   const productData = products.find(product => product.id === id);
     return <Details {...props} product={productData} />
   }}
   </Route>
}
```

Comment: @prinak wow, i don't a lot here. never saw that `render` thing. But whats `{...props}`?

Comment: It denotes all other props. If your params does contain other than id params and if we are going to use that param in Details component than we need to pass it as props as well.